# $T \circ L$ is linear if $L$ is linear

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $V$ be a vector space, and let $T$ and $L$ be any functions from V to V. Is it true that for any $T$, if $L$ is linear and if $T(0)=L(0)=0$, then $T \circ L$ is also linear?

Update: This is false, I forgot to use the product rule in my proof so this can't be true

Comment: The answer is no.

Comment: This will require that $T$ be linear also.  If $T$ and $L$ are both linear, then $T\circ L$ is linear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take $L$ to be the identity operator and $T$ to be any non-linear map with $T(0)=0$.

Answer (score 0):

$V=\mathbb{R}$, Take $T(x)=x^2$ and $L(x)=x, T\circ L(x)=x^2$.